# How to get minimum bounding box for a set of polygons using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a set of polygons in Postgres which I'd like to get the minimum bounding box for them:

[image: Set of polygons]

Something like this:

[image: bounding box]

I've tried ST_Union with ST_Envelope, however they yield something like this:
[image: st_union]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Use [ST_OrientedEnvelope](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_OrientedEnvelope.html)

Comment: Or maybe use: "SELECT ST_ConvexHull(ST_Collect(geom)) geom
FROM <name_table>" :-)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A bounding box is usually defined to be aligned to the axes of the coordinate system. That is what [ST_Envelope](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Envelope.html) creates.

To get the geometry you drew, you can use [ST_OrientedEnvelope](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_OrientedEnvelope.html) instead.